# Hide logo in Adobe Form dynamically?

Tags: adobe, sap-basis, livecycle-designer, adobe-form

How do I set the visibility of an image in Adobe form based on page title.
The page title will be different on each page, based on the value of page title set the visibility of the image.

```
data.#pageSet[0].Page1.AUSTRALIAN_LOGO::initialize - (FormCalc, client)
if( it_title.data.flag.rawValue == 'X' ) then
$.presence = "hidden";
endif

data.#pageSet[0].Page1.GLOBAL_LOGO::initialize - (FormCalc, client)
$.presence = "hidden";
```

The if condition is not working, but the one without the if condition is working
Is the syntax correct?

Comment: Look for hierarchy of the data flag. Navigate to the data node.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
var flag = this.boundItem(xfa.event.newText)

if (flag eq "X")

 then AUSTRALIAN_LOGO.presence = "visible"

 else AUSTRALIAN_LOGO.presence = "hidden"

endif
```

in the exit event of your logo. And don't forget to set that form to [dynamic](https://blogs.sap.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/2_248411.jpg).